# populating dropdownlist based on the condition when you click on add button in phpgrid

Tags: php, phpgrid

I am using phpgrid in my project and i wanted to see a dropdownlist to be populated based on the condition.

When i click on the add buttoon in phpgrid, it will allow me to select the Country and based on the country selected, the dropdownlist to be generated which belonging to the selected country.
In my MySQL database i have a location tables separated with parent and child columns and i can able to see the proper result in mysql views. The same thing i wanted to implement with phpgrid.

***Ref: http://phpgrid.com/***

Answer (score 1):

Have you read http://phpgrid.com/example/nested-dropdown/ ? Seems what you are looking for.